# How to call Go function of test1 in test2

Tags: go

go file in  as below

```
package goClientLib
import (
     ....
)
//The following function will read Command Line Inputs and will return 3 strings
func readInput() (string, string, string){
    var (clientRequest, clientId, clientPassword string)
    argsLen := len(os.Args)
    fmt.Println("Arg Length:",argsLen)
    if len(os.Args) != 4 {
        fmt.Fprintf(os.Stderr, "Usage: %s URL\n", os.Args[0])
        os.Exit(1)
    } else {
        clientRequest = strings.Join(os.Args[1:2],"")
        clientId = strings.Join(os.Args[2:3],"")
        clientPassword = strings.Join(os.Args[3:4],"")
    }

    return clientRequest, clientId, clientPassword
}
```

Now I am trying to use it in Test2.go file as shown below:

```
package main
import (
    "os"
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
    "io"
    "log"
    "goClientLib"
)

func main() {
    clientRequest, clientId, clientPassword := goClientLib.readInput()
    host := goClientLib.generateRequest(clientRequest)
    fmt.Println("clientRequest:",clientRequest)
    fmt.Println("clientId:",clientId)
    fmt.Println("clientPassword:",clientPassword)
    fmt.Println("host:",host)
    response, err := http.Get(host)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    } else {
        defer response.Body.Close()
        _, err := io.Copy(os.Stdout, response.Body)
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }
    }
}
```

I am using Following File Structure

```
src/test2.go
src/goClientLib/test1.go
```

But This code Give me following error while running

```
# command-line-arguments
src\goClientMain.go:15: cannot refer to unexported name goClientLib.readInput
src\goClientMain.go:16: cannot refer to unexported name goClientLib.generateRequest
src\goClientMain.go:16: undefined: goClientLib.generateRequest
```

Comment: The compiler error is pretty clear: You have absolutely no access to unexported stuff from other packages. Export. And read https://golang.org/doc/code.html .

Comment: @Volker Not completely correct. You can access some unexported stuff (e.g. unexported struct Fields) with reflect package. It's usually a bad idea though. And I don't think there's any way to access unexported functions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Volker commented, in order to access functions from another package, 1st letter of function name must be capital. In your case, change `readInput()` to `ReadInput()` and `generateRequest()` to `GenerateRequest()` and make sure `GenerateRequest()` function is defined in `goClientLib` package. Chack [this](https://www.goinggo.net/2014/03/exportedunexported-identifiers-in-go.html) for more information.